# Get model name from instance of Spine.js Model

Tags: javascript, spine.js

Is it possible to get the model name from an instance of a spine js model?  For example, say I have the following object:

```
var Client = Spine.Model.sub();
Client.configure('Client', 'id', 'name');
```

If I pass an instance of the object to a method, is it possible to get the model name?

```
var client = new Client([id: '0', name: 'Anne']);
derp(client);
```

Something like:

```
function derp(c){
  c.class() => 'Client'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(client).constructor.className
```

or

```
client.__proto__.constructor.className
```

`__proto__` is deprecated and will be removed from javascript going forward, but works in old browsers. `Object.getPrototypeOf` should work in modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the name property: Client.name

Comment: I was looking to get the class name from an instance of the class.